# How to get different parameters for different APIs like mentioned below

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, api, spring-rest

I need to get different parameters in response for 2 different APIs `getAll`and `getbyID`.
Now I get the same result -`second json` for both APIs.

I want to get 1st json in reponse of api `getALL` without the one-to-many relation and 
I want to get 2nd json in reponse of api `getbyid` with one-to-many relation

First JSON Response:

```
    {
     "id":2,
     "itemName":"book",

    }
```

Second JSON Response:

```
      {
     "id":2,
     "itemName":"book",
     "owner":
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"John"
        }
    }
```

User Class

```java
    public class User {
        public int id;
        public String name;

        @JsonBackReference
        public List<Item> userItems;
    }
```

Item class

```java
    public class Item {
        public int id;
        public String itemName;

        @JsonManagedReference
        public User owner;
    }
```

can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to make item class just for data transfer like:

```java
public class ItemDTO {
 public int id;
 public String itemName;
}
```

Then in your controller you can do something like that:

```java
@GetMapping('/get-all')
public ResponseEntity<ItemDTO> getAll() {
 //get Item object
 Item item = //e.g database call
 ItemDTO itemDTO = new ItemDTO(item.id, item.name);

 return ResponseEntity.ok(itemDTO);
}

@GetMapping('/get-by-id/{id}')
public ResponseEntity<Item> getAll(@PathVariable Integer id) {
 Item item = //e.g get item by id

 return ResponseEntity.ok(item);
}
```